# How can I generate all unique nested 2-tuples (nested pairings) of a set of n objects in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

By nested 2-tuples, I mean something like this: `((a,b),(c,(d,e)))` where all tuples have two elements. I don't need different orderings of the elements, just the different ways of putting parentheses around them. For `items = [a, b, c, d]`, there are 5 unique pairings, which are:

```
(((a,b),c),d)  
((a,(b,c)),d)  
(a,((b,c),d))  
(a,(b,(c,d)))  
((a,b),(c,d))
```

In a perfect world I'd also like to have control over the maximum depth of the returned tuples, so that if I generated all pairings of `items = [a, b, c, d]` with `max_depth=2`, it would only return `((a,b),(c,d))`.

This problem turned up because I wanted to find a way to generate the results of addition on non-commutative, non-associative numbers. If `a+b` doesn't equal `b+a`, and `a+(b+c)` doesn't equal `(a+b)+c`, what are all the possible sums of a, b, and c?

I have made a function that generates all pairings, but it also returns duplicates.

```
import itertools

def all_pairings(items):
    if len(items) == 2:
        yield (*items,)
    else:
        for i, pair in enumerate(itertools.pairwise(items)):
            for pairing in all_pairings(items[:i] + [pair] + items[i+2:]):
                yield pairing
```

For example, it returns `((a,b),(c,d))` twice for `items=[a, b, c, d]`, since it pairs up `(a,b)` first in one case and `(c,d)` first in the second case.

Returning duplicates becomes a bigger and bigger problem for larger numbers of items. With duplicates, the number of pairings grows factorially, and without duplicates it grows exponentially, according to the Catalan Numbers (https://oeis.org/A000108).

| n | With duplicates: (n-1)! | Without duplicates: (2(n-1))!/(n!(n-1)!) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 |
| 5 | 24 | 14 |
| 6 | 120 | 42 |
| 7 | 720 | 132 |
| 8 | 5040 | 429 |
| 9 | 40320 | 1430 |
| 10 | 362880 | 4862 |

Because of this, I have been trying to come up with an algorithm that doesn't need to search through *all* the possibilities, only the unique ones. Again, it would also be nice to have control over the maximum depth, but that could probably be added to an existing algorithm. So far I've been unsuccessful in coming up with an approach, and I also haven't found any resources that cover this specific problem. I'd appreciate any help or links to helpful resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a recursive generator:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def split(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l[0]
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        for a in split(l[:i]):
            for b in split(l[i:]):
                yield (a, b)
        
list(split(items))
```

Output:

```
[('a', ('b', ('c', 'd'))),
 ('a', (('b', 'c'), 'd')),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a', ('b', 'c')), 'd'),
 ((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 'd')]
```

Check of uniqueness:

```
assert len(list(split(list(range(10))))) == 4862
```

Reversed order of the items:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def split(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l[0]
    for i in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
        for a in split(l[:i]):
            for b in split(l[i:]):
                yield (a, b)
        
list(split(items))

[((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 'd'),
 (('a', ('b', 'c')), 'd'),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')),
 ('a', (('b', 'c'), 'd')),
 ('a', ('b', ('c', 'd')))]
```

With `maxdepth`:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def split(l, maxdepth=None):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l[0]
    elif maxdepth is not None and maxdepth <= 0:
        yield tuple(l)
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(l)):
            for a in split(l[:i], maxdepth=maxdepth and maxdepth-1):
                for b in split(l[i:], maxdepth=maxdepth and maxdepth-1):
                    yield (a, b)

list(split(items))
# or
list(split(items, maxdepth=3))
# or
list(split(items, maxdepth=2))

[('a', ('b', ('c', 'd'))),
 ('a', (('b', 'c'), 'd')),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a', ('b', 'c')), 'd'),
 ((('a', 'b'), 'c'), 'd')]

list(split(items, maxdepth=1))

[('a', ('b', 'c', 'd')),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a', 'b', 'c'), 'd')]

list(split(items, maxdepth=0))

[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Comment: Just a performance comment: `yield from itertools.product(split(l[:i]), split(l[i:]))` would probably provide a massive speedup over the two nested for loops, since it would cache the return value and also creates the pairs in C code. Still the same asymptotic time complexity, just faster.

Comment: Just tested-  that provides about a 3x speedup. If you also cache the results with `functools.cache` and return concrete lists instead of producing a generator, you get another ~20x speedup.  Goes from about 6sec to 0.08sec for input of size 14.

Comment: Actually, I'll just post the changes- save you from reverse engineering them from my descriptions

Comment: @Dillon you're absolutely right, I initially thought of using `itertools` and then decided to go with python without imports ;)

Comment: I needed this exact function. Saved me hours.

Answer (score 5):

Full-credit to mozway for the algorithm - my original idea was to represent the pairing in reverse-polish notation, which would not have lent itself to the following optimizations:

First, we replace the two nested loops:

```py
for a in split(l[:i]):
    for b in split(l[i:]):
        yield (a, b)
```

-with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which will itself cache the results of the inner `split(...)` call, as well as produce the pairing in internal C code, which will run much faster.

```py
yield from product(split(l[:i]), split(l[i:]))
```

Next, we cache the results of the previous `split(...)` calls. To do this we must sacrifice the laziness of generators, as well as ensure that our function parameters are hashable. Explicitly, this means creating a wrapper that casts the input list to a tuple, and to modify the function body to return lists instead of yielding.

```py
def split(l):
    return _split(tuple(l))

def _split(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[:1]
    
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        res.extend(product(_split(l[:i]), _split(l[i:])))
    return res
```

We then decorate the function with [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), to perform the caching. So putting it all together:

```py
from itertools import product
from functools import cache

def split(l):
    return _split(tuple(l))

@cache
def _split(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[:1]
    
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        res.extend(product(_split(l[:i]), _split(l[i:])))
    return res
```

Testing for following input-

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']`
```

-produces the following timings:

```
Original: 5.922573089599609
Revised: 0.08888077735900879
```

I did also verify that the results matched the original exactly- order and all.

Again, full credit to mozway for the algorithm. I've just applied a few optimizations to speed it up a bit.

Comment: Just tested it myself, amazing results! Thank you so much! The time complexity just disappeared - it now pairs 15 items faster than it used to pair 5. Gotta learn this functools magic :D. How would you allow for depth control though? If there's no way to make that still run quickly, that's fine. It's still very fast.

Comment: Actually, false alarm. I was using `timeit('all_pairings(list(range(15)))', globals=globals())` to check the speed. I realize now that it was probably just using the cached results from when I timed it for fewer elements, and that's why the speedup was so drastic. When trying `timeit('all_pairings([random.random()] * 15)', globals=globals())`, the time was much more realistic. Still a big speedup!

Comment: why do we need the wrapper? split("abcd") and _split("abcd) return the exact same thing.

Comment: @JakeB. because `_split` can only accept hashable iterables (since its decorated with `cache`), so if you passed a list or set, it would error. That's why it needs wrapped to be cast to an (immutable) tuple.